# trigger after insert delete query not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

I am writing trigger to work after insert and check if count records more than 500   make delete one record but not work this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delrecord` after insert on `tbl_coins`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE recordcount INT;
DECLARE deleterecordcount INT;

set recordcount = (select count(*) from tbl_coins);

if recordcount > 500

then
set deleterecordcount = (select ID from tbl_coins order by time asc   limit 1);

delete from tbl_coins 

where ID = deleterecordcount;

end if;
END
```

Comment: `A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.`, see [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).